# Построения маршрута по ЖД дороге

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps

Как построить маршрут по ЖД дороге от точки А до Б используя полилинию. Сделал но оно строит маршрут просто, не учитывая дорог.

```
<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.379433, 31.165579999999977),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.9077, 34.79809999999998),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.4501, 30.523400000000038),
    
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    travel_mode:'driving'
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Интересная задача! Можно подробнее, с дорогами? или может ссылку дадите на задачу.

Comment: Нужно создать карту, на которой нужно нанести маршрут от города А до города Б по ЖД дороге. Использовать нужно инструмент в API полилиния.